# Распределить значения массивов по определенному алгоритму

Tags: php

К примеру есть 3 массива:

```
Цвет - array('синий', 'красный', 'зелёный')
Размер - array(36, 37, 38)
Сторона - array('левый', 'правый')
```

Нужно получить из этих массивов все возможные варианты, т.е.

```
Цвет: синий Размер: 36 Сторона: Левая
Цвет: синий Размер: 36 Сторона: Правая
Цвет: синий Размер: 37 Сторона: Левая
Цвет: синий Размер: 37 Сторона: Правая
Цвет: синий Размер: 38 Сторона: Левая
Цвет: синий Размер: 38 Сторона: Правая
Цвет: красный Размер: 36 Сторона: Левая
Цвет: красный Размер: 36 Сторона: Правая
Цвет: красный Размер: 37 Сторона: Левая
...
Цвет: зелёный Размер: 38 Сторона: Правая
```

Количество массивов может быть разное, и количество значений тоже варьируется произвольно. Вроде задача лёгкая, но ни как не могу придумать как сделать это грамотно, по какому алгоритму.

Comment: Вложенные циклы.

Comment: пример пожалуйста приведите, если количество массивов поменяется то что получится?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311779/5441700

Comment: Visman, спасибо! то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Собрать многомерный массив

```
$m = array(
'Цвет' => array('синий', 'красный', 'зелёный'),
'Размер' => array(36, 37, 38),
'Сторона' => array('левый', 'правый')
);
```

Обрабатываем его так

```
$res = array();
while($m){
    $next = array_shift($m);
    $res_next = array();
    foreach($next as $k => $v){
        foreach($res as $kk => $vv){
            $res_next = $vv;
            $res_next[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    $res = $res_next;
}
```

На выходе получим массив $res приблизительно такой

```
array(
array('Цвет'=> 'синий', 'Размер'=> 36,  'Сторона' => 'Левая'),
array('Цвет'=> 'синий', 'Размер'=> 36,  'Сторона' => 'Правая'),
...
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению ваш код не выполняет то что требуется